# Finding Stale data in a SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm creating a phone directory for just a personal project/fun. I'm learning to code. I'm coding in C#/ASP.NET. I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible.

Here it is I'm trying to find a way to automatically email users when their telephone information is 30 days stale in the database and that they need to update it on the web page/app.

How do I go about figuring out how data is stale in a database? Does SQL Server have the ability to scan a particular column (let's say telephone)pick out data that is 30 days old and then look at the email column and send a warning to the user that their information needs updating?

Comment: Use additional column: `LastUpdateDate`.

Comment: No - you will need to implement something in your tables (yes - each one) that can be used to determine when a row (or a column in a row) is "stale". And I've never heard of a phone number being stale - mine hasn't changed in many years.

Comment: SQL Server (generally) does not track metadata like that, features like auditing excepted. The usual solution is to explicitly include a column that records the last time the data was changed so you can query that. This column can be filled with a trigger if the application that performs the actual change can't be modified to include it.

Comment: You need to add your own `Date` or `DateTime` column for this. SQL Server is "just" a bag of Tables containing bags of Columns with virtually no predefined logic.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I'll be incorporating the suggestions.